# Python 'if' within assignment acceptable?

Tags: python

Friday I had a discussion with someone about the following contruction:

```
class C(....

c = C()
d = C()
...

(c if some_boolean else d).some_function_of_class_C()
```

Is this kind of if statement acceptable/encouraged?

The problem is that a lot of people I work with have C experience but not that much Python experience and are not used to such statement (same like list comprehension).
However, Python is not C and I think the advantages of the Python language should be used.
Or not?

(btw, I use normal function names and variable names but it is just for the sake of this example to keep it sample. Also I do not only call f() but some more functions (like f().g() which I woud have to repeat completely in that case.

Comment: It's trivial to transliterate your example into C++ (and OO-ish C): `C c; C d; ... (some_boolean ? c : d)->some_function_of_class_C();` It's still a terribly idea in C though.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "'if' within assignment"?

Comment: @MarkByers Probably just misuse of the term "assignment". A lot of people have a terrible grasp on grammars, and specifically what part of the grammar has which name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's nothing technically wrong with your code, but it is a little odd and surprising to see code like that.

Splitting your statement into two separate statements improves the readability:

```
c = c1 if some_boolean else c2
c.some_function_of_class_C()
```

The terrible variable names you have chosen still make it look awful. But changing the variable names also helps to improve the readability:

```
vehicle = plane if distance > 1000 else car
vehicle.travel()
```

That is a *lot* more readable than what you originally proposed, in my opinion, and it only took a very small change.

Comment: I changed the variable names to simpler names just for sake of the (general) example. In my own code after the . is not only just one function, but a few. I add it in my question.

Answer (score 3):

It is syntactically and semantically valid, but it certainly isn't Pythonic. Consider using the Strategy pattern instead.

Comment: The reason is I don't like multi line if statements which can be avoided. The Strategy pattern doesn't help much in it, since it result in even more code.

Answer (score 1):

Writing code in one language but using the styles and limitations of another language are never a good idea in the long run. Your python code should always be [pythonic](http://chrisarndt.de/talks/rupy/2008/output/slides.html).

That said, make sure your code is readable assuming that the person reading the code understands python syntax, or at least enough to google the rest.

Comment: +1 for the pythonic link, although some items are subjective/personal coding conventions.